# Browser is showing PHP code instead of processing it

Tags: php, xampp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP code is not being executed (i can see it on source code of page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page)
>   [web browser not processing PHP code as PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932913/web-browser-not-processing-php-code-as-php-code)

I have installed XAMPP on my computer which is Windows 8 pro. I use to work with Windows 7 
every time I run the *`index.php`* file on Windows 8 it shows the code on the browser IE10.

Here is what I have done:

1. I have named the file correctly: *`index.php`*
2. I have installed the server and saved the files inside *`c:/xampp/htdocs/PHP/`*
3. I have used `<?php ?>` to open and close all PHP tags
   and everything else seems working fine, like, PHPMyAdmin, and the php.ini file

I don't know whats wrong and it is driving me crazy ...

Farris

Comment: is the url `http://localhost ... index.php` and NOT `file:/// ...`??

Comment: Are you using short php tags? Like `<?` ? If you are that could cause problems.

Comment: @Dagon when I open the file the location is file:///C:// not localhost/

Comment: well that's the problem. your  reading the 'raw' file with the browser, you need to parse it through the webserver (with php). type (copy paste) `http://localhost/index.php` or maybe its `http://localhost/PHP/index.php` in the browser

Comment: @smottt I am using the full <?php tags

Comment: and many other duplicates, https://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com+php%20browser%20shows%20php%20code,%20doesn't%20run

Comment: @Dagon how can I parse it through the webserver with PHP?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is you're not parsing the file via the web server, but accessing it directly.

you need to use the url:

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

or maybe (based on your path above) its

```
http://localhost/PHP/index.php
```

in the browser

Comment: usually trought httpd.conf can configure all needed directories to be accessible via browser. By default it's only one document root which will execute PHP code

Comment: yup, but lets get the basics working first ;-)