# Trouble launching php files

Tags: php, xampp

Im having some problems running php files on my localhost. 
When I run them in the browser all I can see is the php code, Im just trying to establish a connection to MySql database. I have installed XAMPP.

For example:

```
<?php

$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$db = 'letsdeal';

$dbConn = new mysqli('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die("Cant connect");

echo "Yes";
```

?>

When I run it all I see is the php code, somebody knows why?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is your Web server configured correctly?

Comment: are you accessing the files through `localhost` on your browser?

Comment: When I try to access via localhost it cannot find the page.

Comment: Its fixed, I had the wrong path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're seeing raw PHP code it may be that [you're just accessing it using the wrong uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241738/browser-is-showing-php-code-instead-of-processing-it) which is taking you to the raw file, not the parsed code.

Comment: Yes, thank you, its fixed. It was the wrong path, long time I did this.

Comment: @Oliver, good to hear. If the problem is resolved, would you please accept my answer so it's marked as solved? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem with webserver or php installation.

You can try to restart XAMP and in a bad case you must reinstall it.

Bye

Comment: Hi, I have restarted, and reinstalled, but still the same, could it be php installation?

Comment: Sure, in this case the problem is related to PHP. Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: Im using PHP Version 5.4.27